# How can I inject template section inside my application?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im building a web application using Angular which receive sections from server side.

Each section contains the following:

- Html template.
- CSS rules.

**note: sections are small in general.**

Im now investigating the best practice to manage the communication between the client and server sides,

my first thoughts was receive the html and css as string and inject them in the document as follows:

```
interface section {
   html: 'this is html',
   css: 'css rules'
};
```

then simply inject them in the document:

```
function addStyleString(str) {
    var node = document.createElement('style');
    node.innerHTML = str;
    document.body.appendChild(node);
}

addStyleString(section.css);



function addHtmlString(str) {
   var node = document.createElement('div');
   node.innerHTML = str;
   document.body.appendChild(node);
}

addHtmlString(section.html);
```

The issue I found with this approach is when removing the section from the template how to remove its stuff from the html and css code?

Another suggested approach is to fetch the CSS as file and then bind the document with the fetched file.

any suggestions? or better approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Angular Universal: server-side rendering](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

With it You can generate angular components on server. And use it in frontend.

Comment: thanks, 
i will read the docs and check the possibility of using it.

Comment: After taking a look to the Angular universal, i guess it render the whole application in the server side, but in my case i have a sections of the web application.

Answer (score -1):

The best approach would be not to fetch HTML/CSS from the server to display it in your Angular application, but fetch structured data (JSON, ...) and render that natively in Angular. Angular is strong at rendering data using templates, so doing it like this will just make your life harder than necessary.

Comment: actually your approach contains many limitations.
the sections i need to fetch from the server are various in type and style

Comment: Then I'd suggest you put them in an iFrame simply.